# How to add a vertical copyright box on the edge of a page in LATEX (Overleaf)?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to place a vertical copyright box on the side of my title page in overleaf. The box contains a few lines of copyright text. any ideas how is that possible?

Cheers

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows us which documentclass you use and how you set up your title page? It would also be helpful to see a sketch on where exactly the text should be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a vertical copyright into the margin, you can start here:
[LaTeX Adding a vertical copyright into the margin](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25457)